# how to write a matlab code for a pattern recognition in neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, pattern-recognition

I have a different sets of vectors for an object. These vectors are different and are extracted from a particular shape. I want to train my Neural Network in matlab to recognize this particular shape. So that when I input another different vectors of similarity of that particular object, the neural network is able to differentiate and output either '1' or '0'

I am new to this neural network stuffs and I hope that someone could give me some valuable pointers.

Comment: You might wnat to take a look at [the documentation that comes with the neural network toolbox](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/nnet/) which contains loads of examples.

Answer (score 4):

First of all have a look to this [pdf](http://www.image.ece.ntua.gr/courses_static/nn/matlab/nnet.pdf) explaining the Neural Network Toolbox.

Here you can download a [tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19997-neural-network-for-pattern-recognition-tutorial) on pattern recognition with neural networks with matlab.

I hope this helps on your task.

Answer (score 1):

To understand machine learning concepts in general and neural networks in particular, this resource will be usefull www.ml-class.org